# Share a Visual Studio project between two solutions in Git

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops

I have two solutions in visual studio (2017), I'm using TFS online and Git repo, ServerSol and ClientSol.

I want to share one of the projects in ServerSol so that I simply can get latest in ClientSol.

How do I do this, as simple as possible?

Comment: Just add the project via "Add" -> "Existing project" by rightclicking on the solution node

Comment: but they arent on the same computer.